# App is not getting installed on mobile (micromax Q380 - Canvas Spark) through "Android Studio 2.1 Preview 4"

Tags: android, android-studio

App is not getting installed on mobile (micromax Q380 - Canvas Spark) through "Android Studio 2.1 Preview 4"

I am getting follwoing error in console:

04/12 18:23:48: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.sampelchromecast/com.sampelchromecast.SimpleActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.sampelchromecast/com.sampelchromecast.SimpleActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity. [Click here for console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THHL5.png)

Sometimes i'm getting this error also:

```
04/12 19:50:59: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/scriptlanes1/chromecast/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.sampelchromecast
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.sampelchromecast"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
    at android.os.Environment.getCanonicalPathOrNull(Environment.java:832)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:78)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted 


$ adb shell am start -n "com.sampelchromecast/com.sampelchromecast.SimpleActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.sampelchromecast/com.sampelchromecast.SimpleActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't figure out your actual problem but some possible causes are as follows:**

1) In your AndroidManifest.xml file the Launcher/Main activity is missing. 
For ex :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

2) Device is not properly connected to system (ADB is not working). you should install device drivers and Turn ON USB debugging mode.

Hope it till help :)

Comment: Checked manifest file. Everything is OK over there. See: <activity android:name=".SimpleActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Ok. The problem must be in ADB Driver which is not installed on your machine. you should try to install driver manually. Search for "Micromax Q380 ADB Driver Android".

Comment: downloaded adb for my mobile but still issue exists.

Comment: the issue was with Android Studio's run Instant app feature. I disabled instant app feature from settings and then created a build from Run >> Build. Apk created and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem can be caused if the folder in which your project is located has spaces in its project name. After I changed the project directory to a new folder with no spaces in the path name, everything started working fine.

My Android device was Micromax Canvas Doodle 4 running Lollipop (5.0). I was using Android Studio 3.1 on Windows 10.